# Laravel : send value of check box to controller without posting?

Tags: laravel, controller, radio-button

I'm using Laravel for my application.

I have made a PRINT button on my HTML page which is simply calling a route, to be able to send it throught DOMPDF to print it to PDF.

```
<a href="{{ route('print_overzicht_facturen') }}" class="btn btn-default">Print</a>
```

Now, in my Controller, I would like to get the value of a radio button which has been created in the HTML this way

```
<div class="col-lg-7 selectie">
    <input type="radio" name="factuur_selectie" id="factuur_selectie" value="1" checked> Alle facturen&nbsp
    <input type="radio" name="factuur_selectie" id="factuur_selectie" value="2"> Betaalde facturen&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="factuur_selectie" id="factuur_selectie" value="3"> Onbetaalde facturen
</div>
```

In my controller I can not find the way to get the value of the checkbox, I suppose because I'm not doing a submit ?

How would I be able to get the value of the radio button please?

```
public function printFacturen(Request $request){

}
```

I already tried three following ways, but it is not working :

```
$fields = Input::get('factuur_selectie');                
$value = $request->get('factuur_selectie');
$request->input('factuur_selectie');
```

Bestregards,

Davy

Comment: You must sent it to the server. JavaScript or a form. Can't avoid it.

Comment: How is your route defined?

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grab the value of `factuur_selectie` using JavaScript and add it to the generated URL, something like:

```js
var val = document.querySelector('#factuur_selectie:checked').value;

var btn = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-default');

var url = btn.getAttribute('href');

btn.setAttribute('href', url + '?factuur_selectie=' + val);
```

Then you should be able to retrieve `factuur_selectie` from your controller.

Probably you are going to need to update the value everytime an option is selected. In that case you can retrieve the value from then `event` itself:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn.btn-default');

document.querySelector('.selectie').addEventListener('change', function(event) {

  var val = event.target.value;

  var url = btn.getAttribute('href');

  var pos = url.indexOf('?');

  // If URL already contains parameters
  if(pos >= 0) {

    // Remove them
    url = url.substring(0, pos);
  }

  btn.setAttribute('href', url + '?factuur_selectie=' + val);
});
```

Here you have a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxxd3/3543/).

Comment: Don't forget to change its route call.
As you are passing an argument using get method.